# Error on SQL Query - Filtering Date in SQLite database Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

Am working with small android project in that I created table in SQLite database.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName(Id INTEGER PRIMARYKEY AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                "Date DATE, Time TIME, Gender varchar);");
```

I Created few rows in that table. This is my table

```
"1" "27-08-2014"    "15:49" "Female"
"2" "27-08-2014"    "16:40" "Male"
"3" "28-08-2014"    "04:41" "Female"
"4" "29-08-2014"    "16:42" "Male"
"5" "01-09-2014"    "11:43" "Male"
"6" "20-08-2014"    "18:50" "Female"
"7" "27-08-2014"    "17:06" "Female"
```

Now I have some filter using **Date.**

```
SQL 1) SELECT Id FROM TableName WHERE Gender='Female' AND Date <= '27-08-2014'
```

This above query Date is consider as **String** and it will check for 27 and lesser then 27 all values and displayed. [NOTE : *It displayed **Id=5** also but this record Date is Greater then out condition*]

```
SQL 2) SELECT Id FROM TableName WHERE Gender='Female' AND Date <= 27-08-2014
```

This above displayed **"0 Rows returned."**

```
SQL 3) SELECT Id FROM TableName WHERE Gender='Female' AND Date <= #27-08-2014
```

This above query is used in C#.Net but here displaying as **Syntax error.**

I need to get exact result that is **Id = {1,6}.** Kindly solve this problem. Thanking you

Comment: Hi @CL Thanks for your suggestion but am storing as `Date` not String and also i changed to **yyyy-MM-dd** also that also not working.

Comment: SQLite has no `Date` date type; you *are* storing strings. Strings in `yyyy-MM-dd` format are compared correctly.